# Sql statement Java between 2 tables and 2 values ( variables)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, select, jdbc

i am trying to do the following and it doesnt accept it.

```
String sql_eco = "select * from orders where EmployeeID=" +e_ID + " and CustomerID ="' + cu_ID + "'";
```

select from two tables and two values( variables)

Comment: Is CustomerID a varchar column?

Comment: But where is the Second table ???!!!

Comment: Instead of concatenating your query, please use a `PreparedStatement`. It protects you against SQL injection and it makes your life easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
String sql_eco = "select * +
                  from orders +
                  where EmployeeID=" +e_ID + " and CustomerID ='" + cu_ID + "'";   
                                                               ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Try, assuming `CustomerID` and `EmployeeID` are both `Integer` column type

```
String sql_eco = "select * from orders where EmployeeID=" +e_ID + " and CustomerID =" + cu_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this. you have misplaced " for CustomerId

```
String sql_eco = "select * from orders where EmployeeID=" +e_ID + " and CustomerID ='" + cu_ID + "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

values variable u wanna say something like this?

```
String sql_eco = "select * +
                  from orders +
                  where 1=1 ";
if(e_ID  != null) {
 sql_eco += " AND EmployeeID=" +e_ID ;
}
if(cu_ID  != null){
 sql_eco  += " and CustomerID ='" + cu_ID + "'";  
}
```

to improve this code u can use `stringbuilder/stringbuffer`